# Can I calibrate colors on a secondary XOrg.conf screen?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, monitor-calibration

I have configured a secondary screen using a xorg.conf file. (This was needed for an experimental setup using MATLAB and Psychtoolbox.)

On the secondary screen, the mouse cursor is shown as a cross, and it is impossible to do anything on the screen. This is the desired behaviour, as normal users are not expected to do anything on this screen. However, it is therefore also impossible to color-calibrate the screen (using a Spyder 4), as it does not show up in the Ubuntu screen list or in a tool like DisplayCAL either.

Is there a way to calibrate colors on the secondary screen?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!